# MonoDevelop and Umbraco

Tags: .net, umbraco

I'm trying to set up an install of Umbraco using mono and MonoDevelop on a mac. I seem to be able to run .net applications through it but can't get umbraco running. Anyone have any suggestions? My .net knowledge is pretty basic to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend:

http://kevinfitzgerald.net/articles/umbraco-and-mono.htm

Comment: Thanks, looks pretty intense just to get it running. Maybe I'll just use web matrix on a VM! ;)