# Umbraco 4.X on Mono / MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, monodevelop, umbraco

I'd like to grab the latest version of 4.X umbraco and get it working on Mono, and be able to edit (and build) the project in MonoDevelop.

There's a great video of someone running it [here](http://topsy.com/vimeo.com/9438884) but no instructions. All I can find is an old and mostly out-dated detailed article as referenced by this SO post: [MonoDevelop and Umbraco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141137/monodevelop-and-umbraco)

I've tried downloading the latest Umbraco source, which since it's a *web site* project won't open on MonoDevelop, so I created a new web application and copied eveything from umbraco into that project. I then included all the umbraco files in the web app project and then added references to all the DLLs that were in Umbraco's bin folder. This compiled, but errors all over the place when I try to run anything - e.g.

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Current has already been initialized. It is not possible to re-initialize Current once it has been initialized.
```

Before I give up and go back to Visual Studio, can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't run on Mono out of the box, but a community member named Can Koluman has actually created a version that does work on Mono and is developing it further. Hopefully one day it has Mono support out of the box. Read more about it here:

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/general/32923-Umbraco-472-on-Linux?p=4#comment131290